# Hyperlink destinations are blank when parsing document with DOMParser in Chrome

Tags: javascript, domparser

I am trying to use DOMParser to parse an HTML page (in this case http://www.iana.org/domains/reserved) and print out its `<a>` elements and their destinations.

I have pasted and run the following code from the console at http://www.iana.org/:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://www.iana.org/domains/reserved");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var doc = parser.parseFromString(this.responseText, "text/html");
    var links = doc.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; ++i) {
      console.log(links[i].text + " goes to " + links[i].href);
    }
  }
}
xhr.send();
```

On Firefox, I get the expected results:

```
Domains goes to http://www.iana.org/domains
Numbers goes to http://www.iana.org/numbers
Protocols goes to http://www.iana.org/protocols
```

However, on Chrome it seems the element href is blank, I get the following output instead:

```
Domains goes to 
Numbers goes to 
Protocols goes to
```

Why are the hrefs not appearing in Chrome?

Comment: `links[i].attributes.href.value` works but don't know why links[i].href doesn't ;(